# cURL and domDocument to parse html

Tags: php, dom, curl, domdocument

I only need a single value from a specific `<td>` in the DOM's nested tables.
There are 7 tables one inside the other and that specific `<td>` is using a class called "LtrAligned".

How can I go about the DOM and see exactly which element do I need and what will bring me back the data I am looking for?

1. What are the methods used to retrieve the HTML that is between the tags ? like:

   `<a href="abc.com">`**this is a link**`</a>` /// retrieve the text value-> this is a link
2. how can I take out the value that is placed inside the tag, like:

   `<a href="abc.com">`**this is a link**`</a>` /// retrieve the href value-> abc.com

I get many errors going through the DOM because I don't know exactly what to look for. Is there a way to actually go about it step by step and reaching that exact `<td>` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. nodeValue
2. [getAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php)